# VM Informatica power centre client to data source connectivity issue in different server

Tags: informatica-powercenter

In my Windows virtual machine, one Unix server hosted where Informatica is installed.

I want to connect oracle exadata dB which is present in different server.

I opened firewalls between Unix server to oracle exadata server. While trying to connect from Unix server using SQL client (sqlplus), I am able to connect. But from Informatica client which is present in same windows virtual machine, it is not working.

My doubt is do I need to open firewall from vm window also for client? If so does this mean, for new data source connectivity for informatica client and server we need to treat them separately?